# Check if auto signed in user is gsuite user

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

Hi i got a domain application which only allows users connected to our gsuite domain to login to.

Recently my boss would like me to integrate [Auto sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)
But i of course would need to check if they are using a gsuite account and not a normal user account how would i do that using the auto sign-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the "hd" (hosted domain) claim in the ID token, as described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/idtoken-auth

Comment: Some additional info you would first need to call the tokeninfo endpoint in order to be able to retrieve the HD value

Comment: @LarsDormans the token can (and should) be actually decoded and validated locally — the tokeninfo endpoint is “for debugging and low-volume use”

Comment: @JoelL Thanks for alerting me of that after googling around a bit i found this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library ill just leave this here if anyone needs it